# Keeps saying "a term is undefined" when it is actually defined?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So, from what I've read and understood, the 1010 error, where it says "a term is undefined and has no properties" means that some variable has not been declared or it has been declared but doesn't have any properties to begin with. Is that correct? If so, then why does it give me the error at "if (_root.removeProjectiles == true)" from this class code:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.media.Sound;
    import flash.media.SoundChannel;
    public class weapon1projectileCode extends MovieClip
    {
        private var _root:Object;
        private var speed:int = 10;
        public function weapon1projectileCode()
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED, beginClass);
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, entFrame);
            playSound();
        }
        private function beginClass(event:Event):void
        {
            _root = MovieClip(root);
            this.scaleX = .25;
            this.scaleY = .2;
        }
        private function playSound():void
        {
            var sndFire:weapon1projectile_sound;
            var sndFireChannel: SoundChannel;
            sndFire = new weapon1projectile_sound();
            sndFireChannel = sndFire.play();
        }
        private function entFrame(event:Event):void
        {
            if (_root.gamePaused == false)
            {
                x += speed;
                if(this.x > (stage.width+ this.width))
                {
                    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, entFrame);
                    _root.projectilePlayerContainer.removeChild(this);
                }
            }
            if (_root.removeProjectiles == true)
            {
                removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, entFrame);
                _root.projectilePlayerContainer.removeChild(this);
            }
        }
        public function removeListeners():void
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, entFrame);
        }
    }
}
```

When it has been declared in the main code as "". And besides, the "if (_root.gamePaused == false)" in the same exact class code works, even though it's essentially the same structure and the same kind of code is in another class and it works, but this doesn't. Why? What is going on here exactly?

I should also mention that the error appears in output log whenever "removeProjectiles = true" and in this case, it's at the end of the level when an upgrade menu shows up. Let me know if you would like to see that part of the code too.

Comment: Why are you declaring a variable as "" and then evaluating whether it is true or not? "" is an empty String and true is the value of a Boolean. Show us the code where you set it to "". That will be where your problem is.

Comment: You should always declare the Type of each variable you declare. Like `var myBool:Boolean = false;` and `var myString:String = "";`. The keyword after the colon tells flash that the variable needs to be that Type. So if you try to set a Boolean to a a string value, you will get a compile time error instead of a runtime error.

Comment: But I did declare the variable as boolean! It's really weird... I have this set up at the main code of the game: var removeProjectiles:Boolean = false;

Comment: Then what did you mean by *When it has been declared in the main code as ""*?

Comment: Sorry, I was writing everything else down and I was going to paste removeProjectiles:Boolean = false inside the "" but forgot before posting. So yes, the variable is declared as removeProjectiles:Boolean = false but it gives me the 1010 error. Any idea why and how I could fix this, because it really doesn't seem to make any sense.

Comment: Is it because you're throwing _root in there? Try removing that. `var removeProjectiles` may not be the same as `_root.removeProjectiles`, and it looks like you have used _root in one place and not the other.

Comment: Nope, it then says "access of undefined property", error 1120, which is expected. If you look at the code I've provided, in public class there is "_root:Object;" and then in the first private function there is "_root = MovieClip(root)". I don't exactly know what this means, but I know that I need this so that I don't have to rewrite "MovieClip(root)" and can just rewrite "_root" each time instead and that to my understanding this will make "_root" more or less the equivalent of stage. I need the _root and I have been using it in all places, so I have no idea what you mean by "not the other".